# Is it possible to use percentage-based positioning with CSS sprites?

Tags: css

I am using %-based positioning to align my background images in CSS:

```
li a{
    background:url(icons/arrow.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
```

I use this a lot on responsive sites, but would like to group these images into a sprite.

However, if I use a sprite, the percentages become relative to the entire sprite image, and it appears I can no longer use my `background-position` in the same way.

Or is there?

Comment: if your using sprites use pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites are not responsive. They are fixed-size bitmaps, they don't scale. So your dimensions should be fixed.